# Stanford CoreNLP: Java can't find or load main class / java.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

To be honest, Java is a mystery for me. I just started a few days ago to learn Python, but now I need to use *Stanford CoreNLP* which needs Java (GOD!!!!!)

When I import Stanford CoreNlp in CMD, it always shows "Error: can't find or load main class ... Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..."
[image: like what the picture says]

But in fact, I have already made some changes in the environment (though they may not be correct).
[image: environment path]

It may be an error of the setting of environement path, but I really don't know how to solve it...

Comment: I'm not sure but assigning an eviroment  variable `classpath` to a file instead of direcory could be a reason for your trouble.

Comment: @Reporter - That isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing with classpath issue

From your screenshot, current working directory is C:\Users(Name) which does not contains code of the SCNLP.

From [Command Line Usage page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html), the minimal command to run Stanford CoreNLP from the command line is:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -file input.txt
```

As you can see, you missed the `-cp` arg which does specify classpath.

You should `cd` to the code directory and use `-cp "*"` or pass the directory of the source code of Stanford CoreNLP as the value of `-cp` argument

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It's really the missing cd that caused the problem!!!! You save me~ without your explanation, I'll be bald due to over thinking  the difficult subject (a piece of cake of you hahahaha)